# Unexpected string error in Jest with './environment/validate.fx';

Tags: react-native, jestjs, redux-saga

In my React Native app, I'm just starting to write a test file, which runs fine like this:

```js
// @flow
import type {
  Location,
  LocationAction
} from "../src/redux/reducers/locationReducer";
// import { getLocationSaga } from "../src/redux/actions/locationActions";
import SagaTester from "redux-saga-tester";
import recordSaga from "../recordSaga";

describe("getLocationAsync", () => {
  const calculatedSimulatorLocation: Location = {
    latitude: 37.33233141,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0004491555874955085,
    longitude: -122.0312186,
    longitudeDelta: -0.05737702242408729
  };
  const startAction: LocationAction = { type: "USER_LOCATION_START" };
  const successAction: LocationAction = {
    type: "USER_LOCATION_SUCCESS",
    region: calculatedSimulatorLocation
  };
  describe("userLocationSaga", () => {
    it("gets the user's location", async () => {
      const dispatched = await recordSaga(getLocationSaga, startAction);
      expect(dispatched).toContainEqual(successAction);
    });
  });
});
```

The test, of course, fails because `getLocationSaga is not defined.` I've stubbed the function in my actions file:

```js
// @flow
import { Location } from "expo";
import type { LocationAction } from "../reducers/locationReducer";
import type { Saga } from "redux-saga";

export function getLocationAsync(): LocationAction {
  return { type: "USER_LOCATION_START" };
}

export function* getLocationSaga(): Saga<void> {
  return console.log("hello from saga");
}
```

But when I uncomment the line in the tests that imports this method, I get this error:

```js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG-local/APPS/QMGTrago/node_modules/expo/build/Expo.fx.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import './environment/validate.fx';
                                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected string

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:471:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:513:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo/src/Expo.ts:1:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.506s
Ran all test suites.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

How do I fix this? Below are some config files:

#### package.json

```js
  ...
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  ...
```

#### .eslintrc

```js
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "plugins": ["react", "jsx-ally", "import"]
}
```

#### babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo", "@babel/preset-flow"]
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue today on a react-native/ expo app that is using jest. I referenced their guide at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/testing-with-jest/. I looked at the following section listing the transform patterns to ignore:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|sentry-expo|native-base)"
  ]
```

This is found in jest config file (mine is jest.config.js). I noticed mine was missing the following: `|@unimodules/.*|sentry-expo|expo(nent)`?`|@expo(nent)?/.*|`

I included those to fix that specific error.

However, I then got the following errors :

The Expo SDK requires Expo to run. It appears the native Expo modules are unavailable and this code is not running on Expo.

I discovered that I needed to configure my jest to work with jest-expo according to the docs.